# Open hyperlink on button click, when hyperlink is in datasource

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm new to AppMaker and not very experienced in Javascript.

I'm setting up a Template Gallery in AppMaker. In each Template page, users can access the template by clicking a link.

Long story short, I'm trying to create a button which opens a Hyperlink on Click.
The HyperLink is custom to each Template page, and the TemplateURL is in the datasource of my AppMaker.

I've been trying to write it as shown below. My database is named Product, and my field is called TemplateURL.

```css
window.open('Product.TemplateURL','_blank')
```

This doesn't work at all. Does anyone has a clue on how to make it work?

Comment: Why not use a link widget instead of a button? The link widget lets you designate the href which would be your url in your datasource and you can also designate that it will open in a new blank window in the link settings.

Comment: Also the way you have your button click event set it will not recognize your url because in this case case you are feeding it just a string that literally says Product.TemplateURL. You should try window.open(Product.TemplateURL, ‘_blank’) instead in which case it is a variable instead of a literal string.

Comment: Thanks Markus! It works, but it just doesn't have the nice layout of a button.

Comment: So you say there is no way to make it work with the button layout, right?

Comment: Should still work with using window.open, but you need to use the URL which should already be in string format. So don't include ' ' on the URL portion.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't... But I'm not able to explain why. See screenshots here : https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xbBm5SxDBKXCdn5-MzWGUBjD2MVOLvYsm43TdUtYv94/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The error log is Product is not defined
at ProductDetails.MainContent.ProductCard.TopSection.ProductDetailsWrapper.ProductOptions.QuantityContainer.GetSolution.onClick:1:13

Comment: You said the button is inside a card layout, like the App Maker grid widget? If that is the case the URL portion may be pointing to the wrong item. Try `window.open(widget.datasource.item.TemplateURL, '_blank')`.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much